# flutter splash screen status bar colour is flickering

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash). Splash screen is showing perfectly. But there is changing their colors of status bar color before showing flutter's home screen.

First color is black, second is light color and third is primary color.

I tried to add
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryColor</item>`

Even tried with transparent. It is flickering. Is there anyway I can change the status bar color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comment it out splash screen meta tag in AndroidManifest.xml solved my problem.

```
<!--<meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />-->
```